# Efficiency of value type when using a JS Object as a set in ES5

Tags: javascript

When using an Object as a set in ES5 eg:

```
var thingsSeen = {};
thingsSeen["cat"] = true;
thingsSeen["dog"] = true;
```

Does it make any difference to use a number as the value instead of a boolean? Which is better in practice and why?

Comment: It shouldn't make any difference. In practice, try it out. But if it really matters, you're probably doing something wrong.

Comment: If you want to use an object as a set, you probably want `Object.create(null)` instead of `{}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store a boolean in a single bit. You need 64 bits for a number.

Then different implementations may use additional memory, e.g. a whole byte for the boolean. But most probably the number will need more memory.